# How to list only n first files in folder?

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I have about 1500 image files in a folder and listing all using `dir()` last too long and sometimes crashes the AppDesigner. Is there a way to list only the first or the first `n` images at a given time?

Comment: Don't think that's possible with `dir`. How would you determine the first n images? Is it based on timestamp or filename?

Comment: It is based on filename. I would be also happy with only the first image in folder. The filenames are almost identical: `d_Seite_01.jpg` (the number changes).

Comment: Are you sure the call of `dir` causes your problems? Just tried it in a folder which has 5000 files and it flawlessly returns in <0.05s.

Comment: It came to my mind that I am in home office with poor internet connection and the data is on a university server... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible, because `dir` essentially is a wrapper of a operation system function (such as the Windows `dir` and the Linux 'ls'). So now you have two (actually three but you're not gonna like at least one of them^^) options

1. it shouldn't cause much trouble to call 1500 files. Have a look if it is really the `dir` command, which causes trouble. Use the *Rund and Time* functionality in the *Editor*
2. use `dir` with a pattern. Eg. `lst = dir()` returns an array of structs with everything in the current folder -- including `.` and `..`, which are usually nothing you need. Use `lst = dir('*.m')` instead to get all .m files. In your case, it can be `lst = dir('d_Seite_*.jpg')`. I am not sure if that saves you much time but at least memory
3. restructure how your data (images) is stored so that there are less files available. You could run a background task that moves only the `n` latest files into the folder *latest_files* and moves them out again if there are newer ones...